# Is there a way to monitor apache with New Relic?

Tags: apache, newrelic

Can I monitor static pages served with Apache from New Relic?

A module perhaps I should include?

Answer (score 5):

New Relic now has plugins. One publisher has already published a plugin for [Apache](http://newrelic.com/plugins/meetme-inc/59).

If this plugin does not monitor Apache for you in a way that is useful, you can fork this project and improve it or create your own.

Comment: does it help to monitor Apache's error and access logs ?

Answer (score 1):

New Relic doesn't have an Apache monitor just yet, and the web application monitors we have see requests after Apache hands them over, so there's very little visibility there, too.

New Relic DOES support a "queueing time" measure that will let you know how long requests are sitting in your Apache and pre-web application layer. This involves modifying your Apache configuration to include a special HTTP header that includes a timestamp of when Apache started processing the request.

You can read more about that here: https://newrelic.com/docs/features/tracking-front-end-time